# How can I easily find structures in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I would like to find and explore some Minecraft structures, like Temples, Dungeons and more. My current way if finding these is to go straight and look around while walking. This isn't very efficient, as I find only few to none buildings each trip.

How can I effectively find generated structures? I don't mind using commands.

Comment: I saw this and thought "What a coincidence, there's a new locate command!" before I realised it was a self-answered question :P

Comment: @TomHart Sorry for that  :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Minecraft 1.11 and 1.12 feature a new command: `/locate`:

This command returns the closest structure of the type you entered. The syntax is:

```
/locate <structureType>
```

Here is some more information about the command, taken from the [Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/1.11)

> - Accepts: EndCity, Fortress, Mansion, Mineshaft, Monument, Stronghold, Temple and Village.

> - Desert temples, Jungle temples, Witch huts and Igloos all go under the Temple category.

> - Pushes coordinates for the closest structure of given type in the chat for the player who executed the command.

> - Returns the message "Located [Structure] at [x] [y] [z]".

> - Will display the Y coordinates as "(y?)" for some structures

Comment: Is this creative only ?

Comment: @ИвоНедев Nope. It's cheats-enabled only. You don't need to be in craetive, but need to have commands (cheats) on.

Comment: Does it work on non-generated chunks?

Comment: @Mindwin I do believe so, at least the new Maps will show you locations on non-generated chunks.

Comment: @Mindwin Yes. When I typed /locate Mansion in a new world, it gave me these coords: 18347, (y?), 12831

Comment: What will you do if you have, say, 1.7.10, or 1.8/1.9? And when you have also mods adding new structures, so seed-to-map generators won't work as expected? Is the coord. location stored somewhere (obviously it is) , and how to access it? What about looking into some .dat files, will it work out, when you cannot use the new command? Your answer is not working for most versions, so...is there a way when NOT in 1.11+ ?

Comment: @AntoineHejlík Yep. The second answer here :)

Answer (score 10):

If you have the seed that was used to generate your world, you can use [mineatlas.com](http://mineatlas.com/) to get a map of your world, and optionally show locations where villages, temples, ocean monuments and similar are generated.

If it's a local game, you can just upload your `level.dat` file (it's in the saved game directory), no need to look up the seed yourself.

If it's a game on a server, you might be able to get the seed using `/seed`, however, most server owners disable that command to prevent players from cheating. With a local game, /seed works as well, even without cheat mode, so you can use this as well if you don't want to upload the `level.dat` file or can't find it.

@CAD97 commented that there's another tool [Amidst](https://github.com/toolbox4minecraft/amidst/) that does the same thing locally so you don't need an internet connection.

Comment: See also [Amidst](https://github.com/toolbox4minecraft/amidst).

Comment: @Cad97 Thanks, I didn't know that one. Edited into the answer.

Comment: Nice answer, +1. Just the `/seed` works even offline, on singleplayer mode. Will you [edit] your answer, or should I edit?

Comment: @RudolfL.Jelínek: Edited it in, feel free to change the edit if you want something else added.

Answer (score 1):

If you play on a world with achievements, like on Bedrock, and you don’t want to use cheats or creative, copy your world, and go into creative or cheats to locate a structure. Although this isn’t foolproof, as sometimes chunks that have not yet been generated might come out differently.

Answer (score 0):

Mineatlas and chunkbase are two good programs.....If you use mods and have Forge installed Voxelmap, Rei's minimap, or Xaero's minimap are great mods another mod is Finder compass.....some still need to be updated    Another way is start a copy of your seed turn on cheats start the world type / gamemode c to enter creative drink a night vision potion type /gamemode sp to enter spectator mode fly till you find structures on surface enter creative write co-ordinates. To find underground structures (mineshafts dungeons fortress) just fly through the ground spectator mode will enter xray vision mode when structure found return to surface enter creative write co-ordinates. save game re load your regular game go to co-ordinates of structures....If playing on a server you will need to get permissions from host or get seed # from host to make copy of world.